# Howto make hibernation work under Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, hibernate

I tried two methods to enable hibernation. 
First method was invoking

> systemctl hibernate

under root. The second was to use [Frippery Shut Down Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/14/shut-down-menu/).

In both cases the system will eventually show me a black screen with some error message and it does not hibernate. I have the latest updates installed. I believe this is a bug. How can I make hibernation work under Fedora 19?

Comment: Please add in hardware details and, also, what that "some error message" is. If its too long to type, feel free to use a camera to take a picture of the screen, and post that.

Comment: @slazer can you add the error messages.

Comment: Also check to see you have a `linux swap` partition ([hibernate](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hibernate) saves the contents of RAM to the HDD's [swap partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap)) and that it is enabled. Does suspend(-to-RAM) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find that hibernation is not enabled by default in fedora's `grub.cfg` and/or `fstab`.

You need to have a large enough swap partition and an entry for it in `/etc/fstab`.

e.g.

```
UUID=da673383-0c15-4b6c-9eab-0d7e425b7d05 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

And you need to set the `resume` option for linux through grub. I did that by adding `resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/da673383-0c15-4b6c-9eab-0d7e425b7d05` to `/etc/defaults/grub`

e.g.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet acpi_osi=linux resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/da673383-0c15-4b6c-9eab-0d7e425b7d05"
```

You then need to rebuild grub. I use efi, so to do it I ran `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`. You will need to change the -o option if your `grub.cfg` lives elsewhere in `/boot`.

Answer found [on ORDINATECHNIC](https://web.archive.org/web/20150823054525/http://blog.ordinatechnic.com/blog/2015/06/08/enabling-hibernation-suspend-to-disk-in-fedora-22/).

**Update for Fedora 28+**: you also need to [rebuild initramfs with support for the resume module](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/fedora-hibernate.html). Open `/etc/dracut.conf.d/resume.conf` and include `add_dracutmodules+=" resume "`. Then run `dracut -f`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following commands in sequence, as root; you cannot do this `sudo` because of the redirection:

```
echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

That is the most fundamental test of hibernate (all other means just use this in the end).  So if that has a problem, then it is a kernel issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my Fedora 19 system with XFCE, because I had to switch my UPS
because it was on the fritz (beeping), and the Hibernate option in the
Application Menu -> Log Out
menu item just worked without me having to do anything.

Just an FYI that with XFCE desktop you don't have to do anything special.